# Acceptable modifiers for Java class

Tags: java, class, access-modifiers

I recently took a programming quiz and missed the following question:

```
Which of the following are not allowable modifiers for a class?
Choose at least one answer.
    A. public   
    B. private  
    C. protected    
    D. abstract 
    E. final    
    F. static
```

I chose protected and static and got the question wrong with half credit. The course is online and my instructor has not gotten back to me about this question, so I was wondering what the correct answer is.

Comment: Did you try writing some code and seeing what the compiler has to say?

Comment: This is a poor question because the answer is different for top-level classes.

Comment: Yes the reason I ask is because the lecture notes specifically said that the other four were acceptable modifiers

Comment: @Iowa15 Your lecture notes are wrong. `private` top-level classes make no sense; they would effectively be inaccessible to everyone.

Comment: Is the question about any class, or top level classes? The wording implies any class.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's what I thought, until I saw "Choose at least one answer". Then I realised that the question was poorly-written. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a top-level class, you can't use `private`, `protected`, or `static`.

For a nested class, all of those modifiers are allowed.